# What is the meaning of "supposed" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm watching the movie "American Psycho" with Christian Bale and in one of the scenes in which he rides in a back of a cab with his girlfriend and listened to a walkman, his voice (he narrates the scene but not speaks in the scene to anyone) says this:

BATEMAN :
I'm trying to listen to the new George
Michael tape but Evelyn-my **supposed** fiancée-keeps buzzing
in my ear.

This is the conversation that follows in the scene for some more context:

Evelyn continues to make notes.

EVELYN
Marzipan. Pink tents. Hundreds, thousands of roses.
Photographers. Annie Leibovitz. We'll get Annie Leibovitz.
And we'll hire someone to videotape. Patrick, we should do it.

BATEMAN
(Removing his Walkman)
Do...what.

EVELYN
Get married. Have a wedding.

BATEMAN
Evelyn?

EVELYN
Yes, darling?

BATEMAN
Is your Evian spiked?

EVELYN
We should do it.

BATEMAN
No-I can't take the time off work.

EVELYN
Your father practically owns the company. You can do
anything you like, silly.

BATEMAN
I don't want to talk about it.

Which of the following definitions applies to what he said?

1. (prenominal) presumed to be true without certain knowledge: his supposed date of birth.

*Bateman presumes that this is his fiance although she didn't confirm it to him*

2. (foll by: to) expected or obliged (to): I'm supposed to be there at nine.

*This is Bateman's expected fiance. They are planning to get married.*

3. merely thought to be such; imagined: supposed gains.

*It is not really his fiance although some people think that.*

4. assumed as true; hypothetical: a supposed case.

*People who know Bateman assume that this is his fiance.*

**(all of these definitions are from thefreedictionary.com)**

So does any of these are the meaning of the sentence in that scene? If not, please tell me what's the meaning of what he says. Also if you could provide a correct definition from a dictionary it would be lovely.Thx

Comment: Where did you get those definitions? The first one is right but there are mistakes in the English also.

Comment: Not having seen the film, I assume it's (3). She seems to think they are engaged, he seems not to.

Comment: The scenario described by Kate is not unusual in such relationships.

Comment: Kate@ If this really is 3, is it possible that the only person who thinks they are going to marry is her and he is just deluding her? This is what the following conversation kinda suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most contexts, "supposed" usually means something is going to happen, in this case Batman and Evelyn getting married, but *something* happened that changed or disrupted that course of action.

In this context, and in my opinion, "supposed-fiancé" has 3 meanings

1. Batman wants to marry Evelyn but Evelyn sort of does not want to
2. Evelyn wants to marry Batman, but Batman does not really want to
3. Something happened that disrupted both sides and the *supposed* future marriage

After looking at the conversation between Evelyn and Batman, I would choose (2) in the above meanings, and this case, (3) in your definitions proposed in the question.

> merely thought to be such; imagined: supposed gains

> *It is not really his fiancé although some people think that*

Based on your question posed to @KateBunting,

> If this really is 3, is it possible that the only person who thinks they are going to marry is her and he is just deluding her? This is what the following conversation kinda suggests

I would not *assume* that she is the only person that **thinks** that they are going to marry, but it is a possibility due to the context only mentioning Batman and Evelyn, and Batman's mentioning of "I don't want to talk about it" *does* give a sense of privacy to their supposed future marriage.

Comment: DialFrost @You said "I would not assume that she is the only person that they are going to marry" That doesn't make much sense. From their conversation, you can assume that she wants to marry him, cause she says so, and he doesn't because he answers, "No I can't take the time off work"

Comment: whoops i phrased that wrongly my bad @StaticBounce. I added a "thinks" inside to fix the sentence. Does it make sense now? my bad

Comment: Yeah, it's comprehensible to me now, although ... I don't want to correct you again, but I will cause it's funny :) you said Batman instead of Bateman twice hahaha but it's ok because the actor that plays Bateman was also Batman in the Dark Knight trilogy :) (and thank you fore the edit)